# Create docker image digest without registry

Tags: docker, hash

due to constraints, the development environment can't access the internet and therefore can't upload or download anything from the internet.

Regardless, I'd like to use docker digests to work with the locally created and installed images. I understand that with `docker push` those digest would be created, which is not an option for our work environment.

Is there a way to create the docker digest without pushing the image to a repository?

Edit:
To avoid confusion, i meant the digest you get when you do `docker images --digests` not the image ID. This Digest can be used to additionally verify the image has not been tempered with.
[image]

Comment: Just run registry:2 locally and you can push and pull from localhost:5000.

Answer (score 1):

The digest is generated when the image manifest is created. With the docker engine, it doesn't build the image manifest, instead using the image config digest for the image ID. The transition to using the containerd backend for more of the image storage process may change this.

---

However, it is possible to output the image to either a local registry, or to output to something other than the local docker engine. A registry can be deployed on your local host using the various implementations of the OCI distribution-spec, including the `registry:2` image. You would then push to that instead of the internet, and have the image digest available there. E.g.:

```bash
docker run -d --rm -p 127.0.0.1:5000:5000 registry:2
docker build -t localhost:5000/image:tag --push .
```

---

The other option is to output the image to an OCI Layout. That is an on disk representation of a repository, frequently used for transferring images in air-gapped environments. To use that, buildx supports this with the output destination specified:

```bash
docker buildx build -o "type=oci,dest=./oci-image.tar" .
```

From there, the image can be imported and inspected by various tools, including Google's crane, Microsoft's ORAS, RedHat's skopeo, and my own regctl. E.g.:

```bash
regctl image import ocidir://./oci-image:latest ./oci-image.tar
regctl image digest ocidir://./oci-image:latest
```

And the [spec for the OCI Layout](https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec/blob/main/image-layout.md) is fairly easy to follow. You can extract the index.json from the tar and get the digest from your tagged entry in there.

```bash
mkdir oci-image
tar -xvf oci-image.tar -C oci-image
jq -r '.manifests[0].digest' <oci-image/index.json
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and especially putting me onto the OCI layout. I might be able to use that...as you might see in my edited comment, it turns out the digest is a red herring for the OP's (and mine) purposes, anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Docker digests/tags actually get created locally. The registry just uses them for indexing and layer caching. If you run `docker build ... -t my-image:tag` and then try to run `docker run my-image:tag`, it will find the image locally and should work just fine in offline mode.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean the image ID not the digest. I edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: Sorry about that. Out of curiosity what problem are you trying to solve by having the digest before it exists in a registry? As you noted, that specifically is for comparison to ensure the image hasn't been tampered with, but since it's all local you already know that.